# Query on rows where the elements of a specific field are not empty

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query

```
SELECT field1,
COUNT(DISTINCT field2) AS numbercount, 
MAX(ADDTIME(`date`,`start`)) AS `datetime` FROM mydatabase GROUP BY field1 
ORDER BY numbercount DESC, `datetime` ASC LIMIT 0,11
```

but my results aren't like I want.
I need to consider only rows where "field1" has any value and is not empty.

Suggestions?

EDIT:
meanwhile I tested the following solution ( adding WHERE NOT LIKE '') and it seems to be ok:

```
SELECT field1, COUNT(DISTINCT field2) AS numbercount,
MAX(ADDTIME(date,start)) AS datetime FROM mydatabase WHERE NOT LIKE '' GROUP BY field1
ORDER BY numbercount DESC, datetime ASC LIMIT 0,11
```

Are there better solutions?

Comment: Provide us some sample data and desired output

Comment: The real solution here is to avoid having empty strings as values. Use `NULL` if the field is empty, not `''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add field is not null and empty statement.

```
SELECT field1,
COUNT(DISTINCT field2) AS numbercount, 
MAX(ADDTIME(`date`,`start`)) AS `datetime`
FROM mydatabase WHERE field1<>null AND TRIM(field1) <> ‘’ GROUP BY field1 
ORDER BY numbercount DESC, `datetime` ASC LIMIT 0,11
```